# Converting one command into different command with different parameters

Tags: macos, unix, command-line

On Mac OS X, this command

```
ar rcs libio.a a.o b.o c.o
```

should be converted into:

```
libtool -static -o libio.a a.o b.o c.o
```

to get correct static library.

Then, how can I automatically invoke `libtool ...` when `ar ...` is executed in command line or makefile? I may be able to shadow the old `ar` command by coming up with a new `ar` command that parses and invokes the `libtool`, but I wonder there might be simpler ways.

Comment: What should happen if the first arg to `ar` *isn't* `rcs`?  And should this conversion be universal?

Comment: @Scott Hunter: There should be arguments (rcs are three arguments). I need to replace the old ar with the new libtool always, so I think it's universal.

Comment: How can `rcs` be 3 arguments?  Your *conversion* seems to ignore it/them completely.

Comment: `rcs` is one mode and two options: `r` means “add or replace files in the ar-file”, `c` means “create the ar-file if needed without complaining”, and `s` means “add/update the symbol table in the ar-file”.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to write your Makefile in a way that lets you specify the command for building a static library. Example:

```
# Linux
MAKESTATICLIB = ar rcs

# Mac OS X
MAKESTATICLIB = libtool -static -o

# Usage
libio.a: a.o b.o c.o
        $(MAKESTATICLIB) $@ $^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to write a wrapper script, it would look something like this:

```
libfile=$1
shift
libtool -static -o $libfile $*
```

You would put that in a file named "ar", make it executable (`chmod +x ar`), and put it in a directory where your search path will find it, perhaps your personal bin directory, or maybe /usr/local/bin/.  (You could also put it in the current directory, if your search path includes the current directory, but that's generally discouraged for security reasons.)

I suspect you'll also need to create a "wrapper" script called `ranlib` that does nothing.

[P.S. My example ignores the odd `rcs` lurking in your problem statement, which I suspect was some kind of an error.]